# What could consistently cause a BSOD shortly after bootup on a system that has long been stable?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, bsod

I was able to use my system since it was assembled 6 months ago. Now every time when I start it, it runs for 4-5 mins and BSOD screen appears. BSOD screen shows some number which is increasing its value very rapidly. Sorry I could not see what error BSOD is showing as computer restarts after 2-3 seconds after showing BSOD.

I have not addded any hardware recently. The hardware is same which was running fine for last 6 months.

To solve problem myself, I tried following things:

1. Uninstall all recently installed softwares
2. Re-install all drivers
3. Re-install OS (Windows 7 Ultimate Edition 64 bit)
4. Re-assemble PC to check if any part is loosen (which was least possible case).

But because of some reason, my PC is not willing to run stable. Even if I am not doing anything, it will show me BSOD.

There are many links about BSOD reasons when I searched on google. These links are very specific about graphics driver issue causing BSOD, new hardware causing BSOD. I am not able to find links which are useful for me as I tried to install new drivers/OS. Also no new hardware is added.

If anybody has faced same problem or know how it can be diagnosed, please share.

Comment: Can you set the option which disables automatic restart on a BSOD? That way you will have time to write down the error. (You can do that via [Control panel] - [System] - (left side of screen) [Advanced system settings] - (bottom of screen, section starts and recovery) [Settings]. Remove the mark near "Automatically restart").

Comment: @Hennes Thank you Hennes. I had no idea we can disable automatic restart after BSOD. I will update my post with detailed BSOD message shortly.

Comment: I just got pointed to a program to analyse blue screens:  http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

Comment: Once you are able to capture the BSOD error code, it will help you narrow down what it happening. Will the system run in Safe Mode without a BSOD? If you boot to a Windows or Ubuntu Live CD does it still crash?

Comment: upload the dmp files, so that we can look at them with WinDbg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention testing the RAM. Put [memtest-86+](http://www.memtest.org/) on a CD-R or USB key and boot from it. If the RAM is bad, you should see problems in the first pass or three. You could also remove one stick of RAM at a time (if there's more than one) and see if the problem goes away. Another option is just pull the RAM and put it back in; sometimes it just needs to be reseated.

<sub>[Of course, don't mess around inside the machine without unplugging it first, and touch ground to discharge static, continuously if possible.]</sub>

Comment: I have Corsair Vengeance DDR3 CMZ4GX3M1A1600C9 Memory (2 X 4GB) in dual channel. Previously I had tried to re-install them. I tried to run PC with only one RAM by removing other. And now my system is running fine on single RAM. When I remove this (working) RAM, and try to start PC with other RAM, BSOD appears. So you are right, one of RAM must have died. Sending faulty RAM for replacement. Thank you Mike Brown.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any error messages my initial thought would be that a critical fan has stopped working, likely either the CPU fan or the GPU fan on your graphics card (if it has one).  One troubleshooting step would be to use software to monitor your CPU and GPU temperatures and fan speeds to see if the BSOD is temperature related.  I would also boot up the system with the case open and visually check that all the fans are running after power on.

The fact that it happens consistently 4-5 minutes after booting is what leads me to that conclusion.  A driver issue is more likely (though not guaranteed) to be more random in its failing.

I would also inspect the system event log in Windows to see if you see any consistent error messages just before the BSOD each time.  That might be indicative of a driver or software issue.

Comment: I tried to monitor my CPU and GPU temperature using [HWInfo](http://www.hwinfo.com/). CPU temp varies between 32-35 degrees. Primary GPU temp is around 45 degrees. These temperatures are taken when PC is idle.

To confirm that fans are still working when BSOD occurs, I opened the case and checked them. They are working fine.

About driver or software issue, I tried to reinstall all drivers, OS. BSOD occurs even after fresh windows intallation.

Comment: Those temperatures definitely seem to be well within norms, so it's likely not a heat issue.  Curious that it seems to happen right about the same timeframe each time you boot.

Comment: In my experience, overheating results in sudden shutdown, no warning. I'm betting it's bad RAM.